# regex [[:digit:]] showing a row with a letter between digits

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a file.txt looking like this:

```
abe
abbe
cde
45a678
ae
cababb
12345
```

And after running command `egrep [[:digit:]] file.txt`
it shows the result two results: "45a678" and "12345". I don't understand why does it show the first result (I tought that regex will only show lines with numbers).

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do not post files in links or some other site or as an image. Please post them in format of text in code tags and let us knwo then.

Comment: Is it just me? It seems no one on this post is quoting the pattern. I know this pattern doesn't require quotes, but without a compelling reason to leave them off I always put the most restrictive quotes I can on anything that uses metacharacters and/or might later be edited. Since there are no embedded vars I'd use single quotes on *all* these `grep` patterns. Again, yes, I realize they aren't necessary here, but I'm that guy who thinks OCD should be "Compulsive Disorder, Obsessive" so the letters would be in order....

Comment: [Difference between \[0-9\], \[\[:digit:\]\] and \d](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414226/56041), [In grep command, can I change \[:digit:\] to \[0-9\]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276253/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Regex [:digit:] only matches a digit and not checking all the line.

For parsing all line you need to use `^` for beginning line and `$`  for end line.

as a result

```
 egrep ^\d+$ file.txt
```

will only match those lines with numbers

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for any digit in line. You should constrain it from beginning (^) to the end ($) of the line and find at least one digit in between (+).

```
egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$ file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `[[:digit:]]` searching for lines that has `[[:digit:]]` so the `45a678` matches so use `^[[:digit:]]*$` to match all only-digit lines:

```
$ egrep ^[[:digit:]]*$ file1.txt
12345
```

Comment: This will also match on empty lines.

Comment: @PaulHodges Yes, you right, the `*` is zero or more, and the `+` is one or more.